# Posicionar etiqueta div HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando sobre un template que me baje de internet ya que no entiendo mucho de frontend. El template tiene una barra en la cual se muestra un menú con los datos del usuario logueado. En la misma barra existía un `form search` el cual elimine. El "problema" es que al eliminar el `form`, el menú del usuario logueado se movió al lado izquierdo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que propiedad es la que debería revisar en el `CSS`?

Gracias desde ya!

```css
.account-wrap {  
    left: 900px; /* Agregue esta propiedad */
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slider de notificaciones -->
<div class="account-wrap">
  <div class="account-item clearfix js-item-menu">
    <div class="image">
      <img id="profile-picture" src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=<?php echo utf8_decode($row['correo']); ?>+<?php echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']);?>&size=255" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="js-acc-btn" href="#">
        <?php echo utf8_decode($row['nombre']); echo " ";  echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']); ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="account-dropdown js-dropdown">
      <div class="info clearfix">
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#">
            <img id="profile-picture" src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=<?php echo utf8_decode($row['correo']); ?>+<?php echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']);?>&size=255" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h5 class="name">
            <!-- Usuario conectado -->
            <?php echo utf8_decode($row['nombre']); echo " ";  echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']); ?>
          </h5>
          <span class="email"><?php echo utf8_decode($row['correo']); ?></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="account-dropdown__body">
        <div class="account-dropdown__item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i>Mi cuenta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="account-dropdown__item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings"></i>Configuracion</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="account-dropdown__footer">
        <a href="../logout.php">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i>Cerra sesion</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float: right;` o `pull: right;`. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Gracias @DjCrazy agregue lineas del codigo a la pregunta, leere los links que pasaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te indicaba en el comentario, basta con agregar la propiedad `float: right;` ya que si lo haces con medidas en pixeles, no te va a funcionar en los diferentes tamaños de pantalla.

Ejecuta el snnipet en pantalla completa y observa el comportamiento.

```css
.account-wrap{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="account-wrap">
  <div class="account-item clearfix js-item-menu">
    <div class="image">
      <img id="profile-picture" src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=<?php echo utf8_decode($row['correo']); ?>+<?php echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']);?>&size=255" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="js-acc-btn" href="#">
        <?php echo utf8_decode($row['nombre']); echo " ";  echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']);   ?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="account-dropdown js-dropdown">
      <div class="info clearfix">
        <div class="image">
          <a href="#">
            <img id="profile-picture" src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=<?php echo utf8_decode($row['correo']); ?>+<?php echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']);?>&size=255" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h5 class="name">
            <!-- Usuario conectado -->
            <?php echo utf8_decode($row['nombre']); echo " ";  echo utf8_decode($row['apellido']);  ?>
          </h5>
          <span class="email"><?php echo utf8_decode($row['correo']); ?></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="account-dropdown__body">
        <div class="account-dropdown__item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i>Mi cuenta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="account-dropdown__item">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings"></i>Configuracion</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="account-dropdown__footer">
        <a href="../logout.php">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i>Cerra sesion</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias!, pude solucionarlo y que quede responsive con float:right; lo que si, tenia position: absolute; por lo que tuve que cambiarlo a relative para que se aplique la propiedad float